# Random String generator python

Tags: python-3.x, random, rpython

I made a simple program in Python to generate a random string with 5 numbers in it:

```
import random

numcount = 5
fstring = ""

for num in range(19): #strings are 19 characters long
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        x = random.randint(1, 26)
        x += 96
        fstring += (chr(x).upper())
    elif not numcount == 0:
        x = random.randint(0, 9)
        fstring += str(x)
        numcount -= 1

print(fstring)
```

Not too hard, right? Except for one incredibly strange thing: the strings it returns are of a random length. I have run the code several times, and here are some of my results:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
VQZ99HA5DER0CES4
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
05PS0T86LOZS
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
E2QX8296XK
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
M5X9K457QDNBPX
```

I can't figure out what's going on... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Without doing any deep-level analysis, you can see that sometimes both ifs will fail (leading to a shorter fstring) and sometimes, randomly, they won't.

Comment: Sometimes, *very rarely*, they won't. On average you'd get 9.5 iterations in the numeric branch, and only 5 will do anything. Pretty unlikely you'd only get 5 or fewer iterations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You flip a coin 19 times; 50 percent of the time you pick a letter, the other 50 percent you pick a digit, but *only up to 5 times*. If you hit the number option more often, you *do not add anything*.

So you build a string *up to* 19 characters, but it can be shorter. On average it'll be 9.5 letters, and 5 digits.

Only pick numbers if you still have numbers to pick:

```
import string
import random

numcount = 5
chars = []

for num in range(19): #strings are 19 characters long
    if numcount and random.random() < 0.5:
        chars.append(str(random.randint(0, 9)))
        numcount -= 1
    else:
        chars.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))

fchars = ''.join(chars)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> numcount = 5
>>> chars = []
>>> for num in range(19): #strings are 19 characters long
...     if numcount and random.random() < 0.5:
...         chars.append(str(random.randint(0, 9)))
...         numcount -= 1
...     else:
...         chars.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
... 
>>> ''.join(chars)
'3M6G97OEHP6TGYRONPV'
>>> len(chars)
19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

numcount = 5
fstring = ""


while numcount > 0:
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        x = random.randint(1, 26)
        x += 96
        fstring += (chr(x).upper())
    elif not numcount == 0:
        x = random.randint(0, 9)
        fstring += str(x)
    numcount -= 1

print(fstring)
```

Comment: This can generate strings as short as 5 characters, i dont think he wants that

Comment: This produces only 5 characters.