# Python Itertools random

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a code to generate passwords (5 chars) from a list of characters, using python itertools:

```
import itertools

def foo(l):
     yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 5)) 

for x in foo('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
     print(''.join(x))
```

However, I would like to randomize this to get random results containing 5 to 7 characters and not only a sequenced value containing 5 chars starting from "aaaaa".
Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Is there any reason why not to use `random.choice`? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Comment: I know secrets.choice and random.choice, but would like to explore this approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random String generator python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316880/random-string-generator-python)

Comment: However I would like to thank you for all the other suggestions.